# How to know the role of current user in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

While a user is creating a new post, how do I determine his current role?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you know what hooks of Wordpress you want to use.  So skipping that part, it's pretty easy to get the current role of the user

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
   return;
$roles = $current_user->roles;  //$roles is an array
```

Now, you can iterate over that array to see if the user has a particular role.

Or, you can use `current_user_can` to look for specific capabilities, if you just want to check whether or not a user has a specific permission versus whether or not they're in the role. For example:

```
if (current_user_can('delete_posts')) {
  //display the delete posts button.
}
```

Comment: Great! This is just what I'm looking for! :) Thanks! By the way, which hook do i have to use for this code?

Comment: Note the WP codex nowadays states: "Do not pass a role name to `current_user_can()`, as this is not guaranteed to work correctly".

Comment: It's just missing this at the end: if (in_array('super_admin',$roles)) {echo 'foobar';}

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you

```
<?php  echo array_shift(wp_get_current_user()->roles); ?>
```

Comment: Can you pls expalin on how it would resolve the issue?